# Asymptotics of $E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 h_i^3}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 h_i^2}\right]$ for $h_i=\frac{1}{i}$ and normal $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, asymptotics

I'm looking for large-$n$ asymptotics of the following quantity

$$r(n)=E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 h_i^3}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 h_i^2}\right]$$  where $h_i=\frac{1}{i}$ and $\mathbf{x}\sim \text{Normal}(0,I)$.

First few values of $r$ can be [computed](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-ratio-quadratic.nb) as $1,\frac{5}{6},0.7622, 0.7237,\ldots$

Motivation: this is the average ratio of curvature and gradient for quadratic form with eigenvalues $\{h_i\}$, hypothesised to go to 0 with $n\to \infty$ (ie, Section 3.10 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.14368)